# Python np.gradient Error too many values to unpack

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I'm trying to compute the gradient of an image for [sharpness check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646371/detect-which-image-is-sharper) but the following code throws an error even though it should be pretty straight forward

```
import os,sys
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

B = Image.open("C:\\work\\tech\\blur\\blur.jpg")
By, Bx = np.gradient(B)
Bnorm = np.sqrt(Bx**2 + By**2)
Bsharpness = np.average(Bnorm)

print Bsharpness
```

Error

```
----> 6 By, Bx = np.gradient(B)
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

The [documentation for np.gradient](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) says

> For two dimensional arrays, the return will be two arrays ordered by axis.

I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466618/too-many-values-to-unpack-iterating-over-a-dict-key-string-value-list) and it doesn't answer mine

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['too many values to unpack', iterating over a dict. key=>string, value=>list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466618/too-many-values-to-unpack-iterating-over-a-dict-key-string-value-list)

Comment: Try `print(np.gradient(B))` and see what it is you're actually getting back

Comment: @cagatayodabasi I have read that topic first and afaik the sollution does not apply here.

Comment: your image `B` is not a "two dimensional arrays" as it contains the 3 channels RGB, therefore your gradient is a 3d gradient (direction in x axis, direction in y axis, direction in channel)